# TON liteclient-build cmake error 23%

Tags: debian, cmake

debian 8 3.16.0-6-686-pae

На голую систему ставил так

```
apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r` make binutils gcc
apt-get install build-essential libncurses5-dev libssl-dev unzip zlib1g-dev file python g++ libncurses5-dev zlib1g-dev gperf cmake
wget --no-check-certificate https://test.ton.org/ton-test-liteclient-full.tar.xz
```

пришлось собрать свежий cmake

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.13.5/cmake-3.13.5.tar.gz
    ./configure
    make
    make install
    cmake --version
    cmake version 3.13.5

cmake --build . --target test-lite-client > затык
```

При сборке вылетает на 23%
cmake --build . --target test-lite-client

```
[ 21%] Building CXX object tdutils/CMakeFiles/tdutils.dir/td/utils/filesystem.cpp.o
[ 21%] Building CXX object tdutils/CMakeFiles/tdutils.dir/td/utils/find_boundary.cpp.o
[ 21%] Building CXX object tdutils/CMakeFiles/tdutils.dir/td/utils/Gzip.cpp.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object tdutils/CMakeFiles/tdutils.dir/td/utils/GzipByteFlow.cpp.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object tdutils/CMakeFiles/tdutils.dir/td/utils/Hints.cpp.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object tdutils/CMakeFiles/tdutils.dir/td/utils/HttpUrl.cpp.o
/root/lite-client/tdutils/td/utils/HttpUrl.cpp: In function ‘td::Result<td::HttpUrl> td::parse_url(td::MutableSlice, td::HttpUrl::Protocol)’:
/root/lite-client/tdutils/td/utils/HttpUrl.cpp:108:11: warning: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second:
     query = "/";
           ^
In file included from /root/lite-client/tdutils/td/utils/Slice.h:3:0,
                 from /root/lite-client/tdutils/td/utils/HttpUrl.h:4,
                 from /root/lite-client/tdutils/td/utils/HttpUrl.cpp:1:
/root/lite-client/tdutils/td/utils/Slice-decl.h:91:20: note: candidate 1: constexpr td::Slice& td::Slice::operator=(const char (&)[N]) const [with unsigned int N = 2u]
   constexpr Slice &operator=(const char (&a)[N]) {
                    ^
/root/lite-client/tdutils/td/utils/Slice-decl.h:59:7: note: candidate 2: td::Slice& td::Slice::operator=(td::Slice&&)
 class Slice {
       ^
/root/lite-client/tdutils/td/utils/HttpUrl.cpp:108:11: warning: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second:
     query = "/";
           ^
In file included from /root/lite-client/tdutils/td/utils/Slice.h:3:0,
                 from /root/lite-client/tdutils/td/utils/HttpUrl.h:4,
                 from /root/lite-client/tdutils/td/utils/HttpUrl.cpp:1:
/root/lite-client/tdutils/td/utils/Slice-decl.h:91:20: note: candidate 1: constexpr td::Slice& td::Slice::operator=(const char (&)[N]) const [with unsigned int N = 2u]
   constexpr Slice &operator=(const char (&a)[N]) {
                    ^
/root/lite-client/tdutils/td/utils/Slice-decl.h:59:7: note: candidate 2: td::Slice& td::Slice::operator=(const td::Slice&)
 class Slice {
       ^
/root/lite-client/tdutils/td/utils/HttpUrl.cpp:108:11: warning: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second:
     query = "/";
           ^
In file included from /root/lite-client/tdutils/td/utils/Slice.h:3:0,
                 from /root/lite-client/tdutils/td/utils/HttpUrl.h:4,
                 from /root/lite-client/tdutils/td/utils/HttpUrl.cpp:1:
/root/lite-client/tdutils/td/utils/Slice-decl.h:91:20: note: candidate 1: constexpr td::Slice& td::Slice::operator=(const char (&)[N]) const [with unsigned int N = 2u]
   constexpr Slice &operator=(const char (&a)[N]) {
                    ^
/root/lite-client/tdutils/td/utils/Slice-decl.h:85:10: note: candidate 2: td::Slice& td::Slice::operator=(td::string&&) <deleted>
   Slice &operator=(string &&s) = delete;
          ^
/root/lite-client/tdutils/td/utils/Slice-decl.h: In instantiation of ‘constexpr td::Slice& td::Slice::operator=(const char (&)[N]) const [with unsigned int N = 2u]’:
/root/lite-client/tdutils/td/utils/HttpUrl.cpp:108:11:   required from here
/root/lite-client/tdutils/td/utils/Slice-decl.h:92:8: error: assignment of member ‘td::Slice::s_’ in read-only object
     s_ = a;
        ^
/root/lite-client/tdutils/td/utils/Slice-decl.h:93:10: error: assignment of member ‘td::Slice::len_’ in read-only object
     len_ = N - 1;
          ^
/root/lite-client/tdutils/td/utils/Slice-decl.h:94:13: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘td::Slice&’ from expression of type ‘const td::Slice’
     return *this;
             ^
/root/lite-client/tdutils/td/utils/Slice-decl.h:95:3: error: body of constexpr function ‘constexpr td::Slice& td::Slice::operator=(const char (&)[N]) const [with unsigned int N = 2u]’ not a return-statement
   }
   ^
/root/lite-client/tdutils/td/utils/Slice-decl.h: In member function ‘constexpr td::Slice& td::Slice::operator=(const char (&)[N]) const [with unsigned int N = 2u]’:
/root/lite-client/tdutils/td/utils/Slice-decl.h:95:3: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
   }
   ^
tdutils/CMakeFiles/tdutils.dir/build.make:582: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «tdutils/CMakeFiles/tdutils.dir/td/utils/HttpUrl.cpp.o»
make[3]: *** [tdutils/CMakeFiles/tdutils.dir/td/utils/HttpUrl.cpp.o] Ошибка 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1773: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «tdutils/CMakeFiles/tdutils.dir/all»
make[2]: *** [tdutils/CMakeFiles/tdutils.dir/all] Ошибка 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:106: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «CMakeFiles/test-lite-client.dir/rule»
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/test-lite-client.dir/rule] Ошибка 2
Makefile:164: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «test-lite-client»
make: *** [test-lite-client] Ошибка 2
```

чего ему не хватает?

Comment: а каким компилятором собираете?

Comment: делаю по инструкции https://habr.com/ru/post/453714/

Comment: Повторю ещё раз: каким компилятором собираете?

Comment: Честное слово, без понятия, просто все делаю по инструкции) А чем оно там собирается мне трудно сказать. Подскажите куда посмотреть, я постараюсь дать всю информацию.

Answer (score 1):

Поставил посвежее debian-9.1.0. Все слету собралось.
**Andrej Levkovitch** спасибо

Comment: У вас, скорее всего, был просто старый компилятор, на 9-ом дебиане gcc поновее будет